# using redux-oidc through steam

Tags: openid, steam, redux-oidc

Now, I use React,
then I want to sign in through steam openid with redux-oidc,
but it does't work well...
I think my oidc client config is not good;

```
const config = {
    authority: 'http://steamcommunity.com/openid',
    client_id: 'myexamplesite.com',
    redirect_uri: 'myexamplesite.com/callback',
    response_type: 'code token',
    scope: 'openid',
    metadata: {
        authorization_endpoint: 'http://steamcommunity.com/openid'
    }
};
```

How should I change it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have to use another library, because

- steam: openid 2.0
- redux-oidc: openid connect